# how to convert 12h to 24h in php

Tags: php

I want to convert 12h time in php which is in this format: **05/31/2012 09:48 AM**

to 24h time format : **2011-11-27 11:53:36**

This is my code line that you can change:

$time= $_POST['time'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
// $time = 05/31/2012 09:48 AM
$time = $_POST['time'];    
//output new time: 2012-05-31 09:48:00
$newTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time)) );
```

[live example](http://codepad.org/OtiXVugf)

**Doc**:

- [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` and then `date` functions for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php All the possible options are listed there.

The first argument to date is the format and the second is a timestamp (which you get with strtotime of the current date string you have).

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($your_current_date_string));`

The format is just off the top of my head and not exact. You can look up the format you need in the table in the link provided.

Comment: I saw that, but problem is I don't know how to put it all together, that's why I asked on SO

Answer (score 0):

http://psoug.org/snippet/Convert_12_to_24_hour_time_and_vice_versa_241.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to use strtotime like this:

```
$date="05/31/2012 09:48 AM";

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

go through below link for date functionality in PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php